# Сортировка слов в строке (js)

Tags: javascript

У меня стоит задача:

> Нужно написать функцию которая сортирует ленту. Каждое число в ленте будет содержать какую-то цифру.
>   Эта цифра и будет означать позицию которую слово займет в итоге.
>
> Уточнение: Цифры могут быть от 1 до 9. 1 будет первым словом (не 0).
>   Если лента пуста - вернуть пустую ленту. Слова в входной ленте будут содержать только валидные значения.
>
> Пример:
>
> ```
> sortString("g5et ski3lls on6 use1 your2 to4 7top")
> ```
>
> Результат:
>
> use1 your2 ski3lls to4 g5et on6 7top.

Мой вопрос в том, как сортировать слова в строке?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `split` по пробельным символам
2. [Отсортировать массив](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988)
   Для этого понадобится выделять число из слова: `+match(/\d+/)`
3. `join` чтобы снова получить строку